# Assembly program which detects all numbers with two integral divisors

Tags: beginner, assembly

For an FASM assembly course I've to do the following exercise:

*"Write a program that takes the number n as input. Then it prints all the numbers x below n that have exactly 2 different integral divisors (Besides 1 and x).*

*For example: 15 is such a number. It is divisible by 1,3,5,15. (Here 3 and 5 are the two different divisiors, besides 1 and 15).*

*However, 4 is not such a number. It is divisible by 1,2,4."*

Full description can be seen here: [GitHub xorpd](https://github.com/xorpd/asm_prog_ex/blob/master/4_basic_assembly/0_branching/4_structured_branching/ex/2_write_code/write_code.txt).

Here's the code I've written:

```
format PE console
entry start

include 'win32a.inc' 

; ===========================================
; Write a program that takes the number n as
; input. Then prints all the numbers x below
; n that have exactly 2 different intergral 
; divisors (Besides 1 and x).
; Example: 15 : 1, 3, 5, 15 => 3 and 5.
; ===========================================

; ------ Usage example ----------------------
; The first "f" is the number n which was entered by the user.

; C:\Users\michael\Desktop\fasmProgs>divisors
; f
; 6
; 8
; a
; e
; f 
; ------------------------------------------

section '.text' code readable executable

start:
    call    read_hex            ; Provided by teacher. Reads in a hexadecimal number from stdin.

    mov     edi,    eax         ; edi becomes the upper limit.
    mov     esi,    5           ; esi becomes the control variable.

outerLoop:
    inc     esi
    mov     ebx,    2           ; ebx becomes the divisor and control variable of the inner loop.
    mov     ecx,    0           ; Counts how many division have been possible.
innerLoop:
    xor     edx,    edx
    mov     eax,    esi
    div     ebx

    cmp     edx,    0
    jne     prepareInnerIteration
    inc     ecx

prepareInnerIteration:
    inc     ebx                  ; Increment the divisor.

    cmp     ebx,    esi          ; Here the control variable acts as the upper limit.
    jl      innerLoop

prepareOuterIteration:
    cmp     ecx,    2
    jne     goToNextIteration

    cmp     esi,    6            ; In case no number was given. Just a blank.
    je      goToNextIteration

    mov     eax,    esi
    call    print_eax            ; Provided by teacher. Prints eax to stdin.    

goToNextIteration:
    cmp     esi,    edi
    jl      outerLoop

    push    0
    call    [ExitProcess]

include 'training.inc'
```

On of the tests I've done:

[image: Testing with decimal 30 (hexadecimal 1e) as n.]

I enter hexadecimal 1e (decimal 30).

It returns:

- 6 => Can be divided by 2 and 3. Therefore correct detected.
- 8 => 2, 4
- 10 => 2, 5
- 14 => 2, 7
- 15 => 3, 5
- 21 => 3, 7
- 22 => 2, 11
- 26 => 2, 13
- 27 => 3, 9

I would say it works. At least essentially.

Nevertheless: 
There might be flaws even bugs in my program. And I guess one could improve it a lot.

So therefore:

Any hints, comments and recommendation by more experienced Assembly programmer very much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> mov ecx, 0    ; Counts how many division have
> ```

This begs for an optimization in the form `xor ecx, ecx`. This will clear `ECX` just the same, is shorter and faster.

---

> ```
> cmp edx, 0
> jne prepareInnerIteration
> inc ecx
> ```

Another optimization this time on compairing. To compare with zero, you can equally test the value with itself. So writing `test edx, edx`. This shortens the program.

---

> ```
> goToNextIteration:
>   cmp  esi, edi
>   jl   outerLoop
> ```

Your code performs 1 iteration too many! Consider `EDI=30` then this code will jump back to *outerLoop* when `ESI=29`, but there it will instantely be incremented to `ESI=30` and so the code will superfluously process the case where the *control variable* = *upper limit*.

---

> ```
> cmp  esi, 6            ; In case no number was given. Just a blank.
> je   goToNextIteration
> ```

I don't see how this comment relates to the *control variable* being 6.
It just by-passes the output, which is wrong because the number 6 fulfills the conditions.

---

What I miss is a test for any user input smaller than 6

```
  call read_hex ; Reads in a hexadecimal number from stdin.
  cmp  eax, 6
  jl   ExitProg
  ...
ExitProg:
  push 0
  call [ExitProcess]
```

---

> ```
> ; ------ Usage example ----------------------
> ; The first "f" is the number n which was entered by the user.
>
> ; C:\Users\michael\Desktop\fasmProgs>divisors
> ; f
> ; 6
> ; 8
> ; a
> ; e
> ; f 
> ; ------------------------------------------
> ```

This is a misleading comment! Since the premise states that the results are to be **below** the inputted number, the line `; f` conflicts in the usage example given.

Comment: All good comments.  There is a slightly more advanced optimization that may also apply.  As a general rule, I try to set up my loops to count 'down' from x to 0 rather then 'up' from 0 to x.  The benefit is that instead of doing `inc ebx; cmp ebx, esi; jl innerLoop` I can do something like `dec ebx; jnz innerloop` (since dec already sets the flags for the `jl`).  This not only saves me from the additional `cmp` instruction, I also don't necessarily need to keep `esi` laying around just so that I can compare it, which saves me a register.